# ReSharper Code Cleanup

Tags: c#, resharper

Is there a way to tell ReSharper to use the `String` and `Int64` type names when a field or method is used on the type ('`static`-ally'), but `string` and `long` for variable initialization?

Examples:

```
string name = "@user";
// but
int compResult = String.Compare(a, b, ...);

long x = 0;
// but
long x = Int64.Parse(s);
```

Comment: Doubtful. In fact, StyleCop recommends always using the aliases, and never using the CLR types.

Comment: Why do you need it to work that way?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you might be able to use ReSharper's "Structural Search and Replace" function.

Comment: It is a matter of personal preference. Lowercase aliases break my reading flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no ReSharper option to prefer `String` over `string`.

This same question was [recently asked on their community board](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/435373;jsessionid=3B6A13F00D38D3EA5FD0334304FE44B4).